Debug a T-SQL script from VS - Unable to start transact-sql debugger
I am running Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT on a machine where I have administrative rights against a SQL Server where I am an administrator.
I would like to use the SQL Server Debugger on a stored procedure. While I can run the stored procedure in VS 2017, I cannot get around the unable to start transact-sql debugger. error.
I am running VS 2017 as an administrator. I have gone through the text blogs and configuration articles with no success what-so-ever. I can run the queries, so I have a valid connection to the database using the SA account.
Are there any third-party debuggers that are available?

"Are there any third-party debuggers that are available? leaving this question in your post is liable to get it closed as "Seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources"; I suggest focusing on what you have that isn't working.

On a different note, have you considered updating to a more recent version of Visual Studio? What version of SQL Server are you debugging?

I have built hundreds of very complex procs and never used a debugger. Just build them up one query/statement at a time selecting or printing helpful data

I am using the latest version of Visual Studio 2022. I am also using an admin account with the SQL Server. I too have built hundreds of very complex procs. A debugger (one that works) is a very useful tool to check the performance, results for known cases at different stages of mission-critical T-SQL script. They also provide a flexibility that you don't always have when you are piping results to temp tables. When I have a tool that can save time and effort, I will make use of it.
